# function; how will i be able to do this

Tags: php, function

I'm having troubles because of my code echo's but it doesn't show the correct output I want.

I want it to read all the grades and output eligible (if there isn't a certain grade) or output uneligible (if there is a certain grade).

Here's my code for the function:

```
function getStat($status){
  $row = $status->fetch_assoc();
  $rows = $row['grade'];
  if($rows >= 80){
    echo "Eligable. <br>";
  } else {
    echo "Uneligable. <br>";
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you use this function? What do you send in as `$status`?

Comment: I think you are missing loop in your code

Comment: What do you expect to be in $rows?

Comment: Not code related, but it's 'ineligible' and 'eligible'.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for loops as quoted from [php docs](http://php.net/manual/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
}
```

Following your initial line

```
function getStat($status){
    while($row = $status->fetch_assoc()) {
        if($row['grade'] >= 80){
            echo "Eligable. <br>";
        } else {
            echo "Uneligable. <br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a loop to print each grade. If you can confirm that `$status` is a table.

```
function getStat($status) {
    foreach($status as $row) {
        if($row['grade'] >= 80){
            echo "Eligable. <br>";
        }
        else{
            echo "Uneligable. <br>";
        }
    }
}
```

At least try doing `var_dump($status)`;